# KendoUI grid auto fit columns

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, datagrid

I am trying to **autofit** grid columns based on its content size in KendoUI javascript.
 It works if you set resizable: true and double click handler.
 But I want set this in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In gridOption's Databound event, use autoFitColumn Method.

```
  dataBound: (e) => {


       var grid = e.sender;
       if (grid && $scope.modifycolumns) {
         setTimeout(function() {
           $scope.modifycolumns.forEach(function($index, item) {
               console.log(item);
             $scope.tempGrid.autoFitColumn(item);
             // grid.resize();
           });
         }, 1);

       }

     },
```

Here is the complete working solution:

[Resize columns in code-behind for dynamic columns](https://plnkr.co/edit/NWPCv3?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use setOptions:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.setOptions({
  resizable: true
});
```

Example: http://dojo.telerik.com/@sg53719/alOhA

Comment: this will provide to resize manually on grid. I was looking for auto resize base on field's content. I provided my solutions. Thanks for looking into it.